# Laravel Error: Undefined Variable - rating_points

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 to develop a web application. In the project, I tried to dynamically add input fields using select option change based on condition. Initially this was successful, but I later got an error.

**Controller**

```
public $rating_points = [
    "1" => "Three-Star-Rating",
    "2" => "Four-Star-Rating",
    "3" => "Five-Star-Rating",
    "4" => "Six-Star-Rating",
    "5" => "Seven-Star-Rating",
];

public function create()
{
    return view('appraisal.ratings.create')->with('rating_points', $this->rating_points);
}

public function store(StoreRatingRequest $request)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < count(Input::get('id')); $idx++)
    {
        $rating = new AppraisalRating;
        $rating->rating_point           =       $input['rating_point'][$idx];
        $rating->rating_type            =       $input['rating_type'][$idx];
        $rating->rating_value           =       $input['rating_value'][$idx];
        $rating->rating_description     =       $input['rating_description'][$idx];
        $rating->save();
    }

    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Rating is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.ratings.index');
    }
```

**view: create.blade**

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <form  action="{{route('appraisal.ratings.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="rating-point" class="col-4 col-form-label"> Rating Point<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 controls">
                                            <select id='rating-point' class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose Rating Value" tabindex="1" name="rating_point[]">
                                                <option value="">Select Rating Point</option>
                                                @foreach($rating_points as $k => $rating_point)
                                                    <option value="{{$k}}" @if(old("rating_point") == "$k") selected @endif>{{$rating_point}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>

                        <div class="row" id="rating-data"></div>
                    </div>
          
            <div id="rating-button" style="display: none;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.ratings.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
    @endsection

    @section('javascript')
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
    $('#rating-point').on('change', function() {
     $('#rating-data').html('');

      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        var numInputs = '3';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         }           
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2')
      {
        var numInputs = '4';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '3')
      {
        var numInputs = '5';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
        var numInputs = '6';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '5')
      {
        var numInputs = '7';
         for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
         {
             var j = i*1+1;
             var $section =  $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_type[]" value="'+j+'" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="number" name="rating_value[]" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group row"><label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><div class="col-md-9 controls"><input  type="text" name="rating_description[]" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}"></div></div></div>');
             $('#rating-data').append($section);
         } 
        $("#rating-button").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#rating-button").hide();
      }
     });
    });
   </script>

   @stop
```

[image: dynamic select option image]

I expect that when the page is loaded I should see only the select option dropdownlist, the when I select on change I should see something like the image above and then save into the the database.

Initially the page was loading, but when I added some code to my controller I got this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: rating_points (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\appraisal\resources\views\appraisal\ratings\create.blade.php)

and the page is not loading again.

How do I resolve it.

Thank you

Comment: There is a lot of code here, and your question is a little unclear.  `when I added some code ... I got this error` - what code?  `when I select on change` - if the page is not loading, you don't see this yet, right?  If the page is not loading, then your `store()` method, and probably most (all?) of your JS is not relevant to this immediate problem?  Tackle one problem at a time.  You could make this question a lot simpler to read/understand/answer if you edit it and remove all that.  Try to a create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the code I added in the controller to save it as an array:   for ($idx = 0; $idx < count(Input::get('id')); $idx++)

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: @mdexp - Line 81 in the view.  Which is this;   @foreach($rating_points as $k => $rating_point)

Answer (score 2):

please change syntax

```
  return view('appraisal.ratings.create')->with('rating_points', $this->rating_points);
```

to

```
  return view('appraisal.ratings.create')->with(['rating_points'=>$this->rating_points]);
```

Comment: kelvin kantaria, The error is still there when I made the change as you advised.

Comment: [The docs show OP's code is correct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views), using an array is not necessary.

Comment: @kelvinkantaria please do not suggest posting screenshots, this is not imgur.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. 
I observe that it was still referencing the old controller I used. I deleted it and run composer update. 
Problem solved.